# Why is my Cyclops vehicle bay locked?

Tags: subnautica

I was trying to get out my prawn suit from the vehicle bay in my Cyclops, but when I went to get it, the vehicle bay was locked. There is nothing interfering with the opening of the doors. (I docked the Prawn suit in the Cyclops).

Comment: Are there manual locks of some sort you can toggle? I can't remember if there was or not.  Have you tried moving the Cyclops somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try to move your Cyclops, and see if that helps. It can be it's too close to the ground or another obstruction.

Secondly,

[image: Have you tried turning it off and on again?]

("It" being the Cyclops.)

Note that the vehicle bay doors will also be locked while the Fire Supression system is activated: if you used it recently, that could account for buggy behaviour.

Yet another possibility is that your Seamoth is too close to the bay doors, 'requesting' it to open simultaneously.